# FK Object in Entity Framework - performamce issue

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am working with Entity Framework and pretty new with it.

I have a table named: Order and table named: Products.

Each order have a lot of products.

When generating the entities I get Order object with ICollection to products.

The problem is I have a lot of products to each order (20K) and when I do

```
order.Products.where(......)
```

The EF runs a select statement only with orderId= 123 and does the rest of the where in the code.

Because I have a lot of results - the select takes a lot of time. How can I change the code - that the select in the DB will be with the where conditions?

Comment: .where(......) will return an IQueryable, and the query will not be executed until you actually touch one of the objects, or evaluate anything there. as long as you stay in the context, this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
var prods = order.Products.Where(...);
```

is equivalent to:

```
var temps = order.Products;
var prods = temps.Where(...);
```

Unlike `Where(...)`, which returns an `IQueryable`, `order.Products` triggers a lazy loading, which produces an `ICollection` and will be executed immediately, not delayed. So it's this `order.Products` part that generates the select statement you see. It fetches all the products belonging to that order into memory. Then the `Where(...)` part is executed in memory, hence the bad performance.

To avoid this, you should use `order.Products` only if you really want all the products on an order. If you want only a subset of them, do something like the following:

```
ctx.Products.Where(prod => prod.Order.Id == order.Id && ...)
```

Note that `ctx` is the database context, not the `order` object.

If you think that the `prod.Order.Id == order.Id` clause above looks a little dirty, here's a purer but longer alternative:

```
ctx.Entry(order).Collection(ord => ord.Products).Query().Where(...)
```

which produces exactly the same SQL query.